# City engine web scene (large model)

Tags: 3d-model, cityengine, web-scene

I have a tag bit of a problem I made a 3d model of a city (about 21000 models) and using the city engine web scene viewer from Esri is slow and eats up a lot of resources unfortunately (and I'm talking about the solid non textured models and I'm not not adding the layers from my analysis) so I can't use the platform to make a smooth presentation, so I was wondering if there is any way to convert my 3D model to a stand alone application that can be run directly from my PC.

I looked into maybe finding a way to move my model to a Java platform and unfortunately I couldn't find any "stupid proof" software because to my great shame I am a potato when it comes down writing Java programs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CityEngine 2016 or ArcGIS Pro and export out a scene package from your building data and create a hosted scene service in ArcGIS Online or Portal and create a web scene which you can use in Web AppBuilder, Templates or create your own custom application. Here is a sample of with buildings coming from NYC untextured. http://www.arcgis.com/home/webscene/viewer.html?webscene=0109e40f40ae42608cf2239f7b4314ae